# Proper way to test POST method in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, unit-testing, model-view-controller, junit, mockito

I've got simple app based on SpringMVC and Hibernate, trying to test a `POST` method which saves a Customer `Customer.class` to the database. Don't want to test database yet, only simple unit testing. Got the test green, but feel is still not enough, how can I refactor it to make it as it supposed to be?

CustomerController.class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

  @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

  @PostMapping("/saveCustomer")
    public String saveCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer theCustomer) {
        customerService.saveCustomer(theCustomer);

        return "redirect:/customer/list";
    }}
```

CustomerServiceImpl.class:

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
  @Override
  @Transactional
    public void saveCustomer(Customer theCustomer) {
        customerDAO.saveCustomer(theCustomer);
    }
}
```

CustomerDAOImpl.class:

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {
  @Override
    public void saveCustomer(Customer theCustomer) {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theCustomer);

    }
}
```

CustomerControllerTest.class:

```
public class CustomerControllerTest {


@InjectMocks
CustomerController controller;

@Mock
CustomerService mockCustomerService;

@Mock
View mockView;


MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
            .setSingleView(mockView)
            .build();
}
     @Test
        public void testSaveCustomer() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(post("/customer/saveCustomer"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/customer/list"));

    }}
```

Comment: verify the call of mockCustomerService.saveCustomer(customer), also you may check that fields are set, which are declared not null in customer entity. Fields in TestClass should be private. You could use @MockBean instead of \@Mock, \@Autowired instead of \@InjectMocks and omit MockitoAnnotation.initMocks(this).

Answer (score 0):

Common errors for something like saving an object such as customer could be the following:

1. Missing property in POST request such as "FirstName"
2. Using a readonly property like "ID"
3. Invalid property types (expected int, got string)
4. Invalid content-type (expected JSON, got XML)
5. Does the request have permission to save this object?
6. Are invalid requests returning the appropriate response code?

In addition to unit testing, I'd highly recommend Fiddler since it looks like you're using Windows.

Fiddler will allow you to intercept every single HTTP request made by your system. This will allow you to examine the requests made by your unit tests with detailed information about your POST request headers, body and more.

https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

This tool is the last thing you do when a specific request fails and you need to know exactly what the request looked like compared to a successful one.